# Is referencing using: require '../db.rb' correct?

Tags: ruby, require

I need to reference my `db.rb` file that is lower in the directory tree.

```
/folder1/test.rb
/db.rb
/database.yml
```

running:

```
ruby db.rb
```

doesn't return an error.

In test.rb I did:

```
require '../db.rb'
```

and I get an error:

```
../db.rb:7:in `initialize': No such file or directory - database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from ../db.rb:7:in `open'
    from ../db.rb:7
    from test.rb:1:in `require'
    from test.rb:1
```

Not sure what the issue is here?

Comment: What Matthew said is correct. One way to solve this problem would be to require the pull path of the file(e.g. require File.expand_path(File.dirname(\__FILE\__) + '/rest_of_path') )

Answer (score 3):

The relative `require` itself is okay.  However, `require` doesn't change your current working directory.  So it's looking for `database.yml` in /folder1.

Answer (score 1):

In previous Rubies, `require` included the calling script's directory. There were security issues with that so the `'.'` directory was removed in 1.9. To provide a way of getting to things in the local directory `require_relative` was added.

http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_2_0/NEWS talks about its inclusion into Core.